# Need Help With Gtk+ Text Editor

Tags: gtk

I am creating a GTK+ text editor called Quick-Ed Pro. It was originally designed to be a cross-platform version of Quick-Ed , a text editor I wrote in raw Win Api. But after finding the awesome capabilities of GTK+ , Quick-Ed Pro emerged as an entirely different program with advanced GUI capabilities way better than Quick-Ed. But now Im stuck with a few problems.
Problems:
1- I want to make my editor multi-tabular like notepad++ or gedit. I dont know how to do this. What widget should I use?

2- GtkTextView does not seem to have any undo / redo functions. How can I make my own? (examples appreciated)

3- Gtk+ has a long startup time, usually 2-4 seconds unlike win api which started up in less than a second, so how can I create a small popup loading bar like the one in GIMP or Code::Blocks?

4-URL of my project: http://code.google.com/p/quick-ed/
URL of the WinApi Quick-Ed : http://code.google.com/p/burningprodigy ... e&can=2&q=

Any help will be appreciated. I need contributors. Please lend me a hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Tabs: You will need to write your own widget for this. No toolkit i know has one that is flexible enough to handle what is required in a good editor. But you can start with GtkNotebook for a quick prototype.

2) Yes this is a FAQ and imho bad that it is not solved directly in GTK. If you use gtkmm you can use  http://view.sourceforge.net/classes.php otherwise look into the library to see how it is implemented and port it into C. There are other implementations for example for python available on the net.

3) You have to write a small dialog using the WinAPI and show this before you call the first GTK function. Usually i wouldn't recommend to do it - after the windows file cache has the files (or you have a SSD) loading speed is okay.

You should look into http://projects.gnome.org/gtksourceview/ to get a good editor. The GtkTextView is definitely not able to work as a source code editor. I'm maintaining a commerical IDE and Editor and by the way the most code is outside the editor widget anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am trying GtkSourceView, compiling gtk or anything gtk based is a herculean task, lol even the binaries dont work properly sometimes. Thanks for the startup dialog tip. The link was awesome, many useful widgets just pleading to be ported to C. By the way, which IDE are you maintaining?